# How can I optimize this 2.x style query for SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, join, sqlalchemy, query-optimization

I am having trouble running this query -- I did have success once which took about five minutes, but all other attempts have timed out. That one time did NOT have the first condition listed in the and_ clause either.

Anyone see an obvious reason why this query is having so much trouble? I realize there are a lot of joins -- although I'm all ears for ways around that too. The and_ makes sure that first table joined from t1 and t2 is already filtered for the smallish date range and tier we need. All of those joins and INNER JOINS once the query statement is emitted for MySQL. Every table has an explicit foreign key for the id column in t1 -- the center table.

Is there a way to only pull the 2-4 columns I need from each table instead of the whole table? Although the only one with more than 4-6 columns that would really benefit from that is t3.

Thank you

```
with Session(db_engine) as db_session:
 
    st0 = (select(t1.id, t1.ts, t2.tier_id,
                 t3.subway_id, t4.result, t5.result,
                 t6.result, t6.model_score,
                 t6.expected_model_score, t7.decision,
                 t7.note, t7.camp)
          .join(t2, and_(t1.ts>'2023-03-01 02:04:00', t1.id==t2.t1_id, t2.tier_id=="42"))
          .join(t3)
          .join(t4)
          .join(t5)
          .join(t6)
          .join(t7)
          .order_by(t1.ts.desc()))
              
    starttime = time.time()
    print("The start time is :",starttime)
    idk = db_session.execute(st0).all()
    print("The time difference is :", time.time() - starttime)
```

Comment: I figured that might be the case -- not sure what's going on here

anecdotally I noticed that running it with double quotes around the date and tier_id resulted in success